# How to open a sliding panel when a grid row is selected

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs6

I want to slide open a panel on the right of the grid when I select a grid row. I want to show some details regarding the clicked row in this panel. This is somewhat like what the row expander plugin does, but I want the panel to open on the right side and take the height of the grid.

Is there already a plugin which achieves this? If not, what components can I use to get this done? I am not requesting the code, but would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for that.

All plugins somehow modify the rows which are displayed (insert a row body, insert summary rows, insert groupers etc. etc.), which you clearly don't want.

Since you want the slide-in panel to take up the full height of the grid, you could just add a `form` to the `dockedItems` of the grid, and set the `dock:'right'` configuration on the form. You would set `hidden:true` for a start, and in the `selectionchange` listener of the grid you would show the form and use `loadRecord(selection[0])` to load the record into it. (Or you could use a container and some bindings instead of a form).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To add one more thing, I had to set the width of the docked item to get the layout working.